# How to provide multiple variables in scriptAction on HDI cluster creation using ARM template

Tags: linux, shell, azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I am creating HDI spark cluster using ARM template.

```
"scriptActions": [
    {
     "name": "Install Server",
     "uri": "https://raw..sh",
     "parameters": "[parameters('clusterWorkerNode')]",
     "isHeadNode": true,
     "isWorkerNode": false,
     "isZookeeperNode": false
     }
 ]
```

1. How can I pass multiple values in parameters in above scriptActions?
2. if "isHeadNode": true, Will my script install on both headnodes? and What about for "isWorkerNode": false and "isZookeeperNode": false . Is it same scenario?
3. HDI cluster is taking more than 20 minutes to create. Is there a way to reduce the time taken?

**Update**:-

I am able to pass multiple dynamic variables using the following and it works.

```
 "parameters": "[concat(parameters('param1'),' ',parameters('param2'),' ',parameters('param3'),' ',parameters('param4'),' ',parameters('param5'))]",
```

Comment: @Walter Kindly reply if you know any answers

Comment: `How can I pass multiple values in parameters in above scriptActions?` What do you mean? Execute multiple scripts?

Comment: Not multiple scripts. Pass multiple values to single script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass multiple values in parameters in above scriptActions?

You could add multiple parameters values, just like below:

```
   "scriptActions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "test",
                                    "uri": "https://hdiconfigactions.blob.core.windows.net/linuxgiraphconfigactionv01/giraph-installer-v01.sh",
                                    "parameters": "install upgrade",
                                    "isHeadNode": true,
                                    "isWorkerNode": true,
                                    "isZookeeperNode": true
                                }
                            ]
```

> if "isHeadNode": true, Will my script install on both headnodes? and
>   What about for "isWorkerNode": false and "isZookeeperNode": false . Is
>   it same scenario?

Script Actions can be restricted to run on only certain node types, for example head nodes or worker nodes. If `isHeadNod` is yes, the script will install on both headnodes. `isWorkerNode` `isZookeeperNode` are the same. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux#understanding-script-actions).

> HDI cluster is taking more than 20 minutes to create. Is there a way
>   to reduce the time taken?

Based on my knowledge, you could not do it except you select less VMs. The optimization of the installation process is controlled by Azure.

Comment: If I want to pass dynamic parameters.  "parameters": "[parameters('param1')] [parameters('param2')] [parameters('param3')]". Is this correct?

Comment: I don't do this test. I think you could test. But it seems that you are right.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: I get error as  expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'RightSquareBracket'. when I use parameters": "[parameters('param1')] [parameters('param2')] [parameters('param3')]"

Comment: What are your parameters type? Like `example.sh parameter1 paramter2 paramter3` or `examples -n parameter1 -m parameter2 -l parameter3`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139943/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-karan).